# Install pip and virtualenv on Ubuntu 16.04 Boot Disk

Tags: apt, live-usb, pip

I've been asked to test some software I've developed on Ubuntu 16.04, and annoyingly I only just upgraded to 17.10. SO I created an Ubuntu 16.04 boot usb drive and thought I'd try my code from there. But I can't seem to get the prerequisites to install.

In particular I need pip3 and virtualenv:

```
$ pip3 install numpy
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
```

So how do I install pip and virtualenv on an Ubuntu 16.04 boot usb?

Thanks.

Comment: did you run `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: @L.Integra Yes I did.

Comment: maybe the problem with sources configuration. try `sudo apt edit-sources` and uncoment `universe` source

Comment: There was no universe to uncomment, but thanks for the tip. I had to add the universe repository, then spt update, and then I could install what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

## **To setup a Python Programming Environment:**

**Install the things you need :**

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
sudo pip install flask
```

**Prepare the envirement:**

```
mkdir py3project
cd py3project
virtualenv -p python3 venv
ls
```

**To use/activate the environment:**

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

**To install pip use:**

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

**Search with pip :**

For example you want to look for a package redis.

You do:

```
pip search jupyter
```

To install with pip, for example jupyter notebook:

You do :

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

Line is the same for python2 pip installs, pip3 use python3

**To see your project tree :**

```
tree myprogram
```

Checkout this link for more information : [how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work from the boot usb. "E: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate"

Comment: It does work from a Ubuntu Live USB....

Comment: Not for me. I followed these instructions: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that the Ubuntu installation on the boot USB that I created (following these instructions:https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) didn't include the standard Universe repository, just a limited version of it. It's a simple fix...

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

And then I was able to install python3-pip and python-virtualenv as normal.